# Specify gcc compiler flags while downloading Haskell bindings to a c-library from Hackage

Tags: haskell, gcc, cabal, hackage

I want to install bindings to the [Minisat](http://minisat.se/) solver for satisfiability problems available [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/minisat-solver) on Hackage.

When I tried doing `cabal install minisat-solver` at the command-line on a Linux work-station, I got the following output

```
user@home: $ cabal install minisat-solver
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring minisat-solver-0.1...
Building minisat-solver-0.1...
Failed to install minisat-solver-0.1
Build log ( /home/gaurish/.cabal/logs/minisat-solver-0.1.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-6317/minisat-solver-0.1'
Configuring minisat-solver-0.1...
Building minisat-solver-0.1...
Preprocessing library minisat-solver-0.1...
[1 of 7] Compiling SAT.MiniSat.Literals ( SAT/MiniSat/Literals.hs, dist/build/SAT/MiniSat/Literals.o )
[2 of 7] Compiling SAT.MiniSat.LowLevel ( SAT/MiniSat/LowLevel.hs, dist/build/SAT/MiniSat/LowLevel.o )
[3 of 7] Compiling SAT.MiniSat.Monadic ( SAT/MiniSat/Monadic.hs, dist/build/SAT/MiniSat/Monadic.o )
[4 of 7] Compiling SAT.MiniSat.Functional ( SAT/MiniSat/Functional.hs, dist/build/SAT/MiniSat/Functional.o )
[5 of 7] Compiling SAT.MiniSat.Variable ( SAT/MiniSat/Variable.hs, dist/build/SAT/MiniSat/Variable.o )
[6 of 7] Compiling SAT.MiniSat.Formula ( SAT/MiniSat/Formula.hs, dist/build/SAT/MiniSat/Formula.o )
[7 of 7] Compiling SAT.MiniSat      ( SAT/MiniSat.hs, dist/build/SAT/MiniSat.o )
c-sources/solver.c: In function ‘solver_simplification’:

c-sources/solver.c:901:3:
     error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
       for (int i = solver_dlevel(s); i >= 0; i--) {
       ^

c-sources/solver.c:901:3:
     note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

c-sources/solver.c:907:3:
     error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
       for (int c = s->qtail - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
       ^
```

Clearly, I need to tell cabal to tell gcc to use ansi-c99 mode while compiling the embedded C-sources. in other words to pass -std=c99 to the gcc compiler.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`--gcc-option`](https://www.mankier.com/1/cabal#--gcc-option) might do the trick.

It's also found in [here](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#programs-used-for-building) as `--prog-option` where prog is any program known to cabal(such as gcc)

Another option is to download the package yourself then modify its build configuration.